# How do I remove duplicate group key values and display detail items (mutiple group)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, window-functions

#### Source Data and DDL

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Order_NO] varchar(10), [MO_NO] varchar(10), [DEP] varchar(3), [PRD_NO] varchar(12), [QTY] int, [STD_QTY] numeric, [QTY_DIF] numeric);

INSERT INTO T
    ([Order_NO], [MO_NO], [DEP], [PRD_NO], [QTY], [STD_QTY], [QTY_DIF])
VALUES
    ('SO17110026', 'MO17110824', 'MO2', '3CA002-00120', 40681, 40380.48, 300.52),
    ('SO17110026', 'MO17110824', 'MO2', '3CA002A00110', 41125, 40380.48, 744.52),
    ('SO17110026', 'MO17110825', 'MO1', '403010060002', 40381, 40380.48, 0.52),
    ('SO17110026', 'MO17110825', 'MO1', '601001000734', 69, 68.102, 0.898),
    ('SO17110026', 'MO17110826', 'MO1', '601002000004', 2862, 2861.4858, 0.5142),
    ('SO17110026', 'MO17110826', 'MO1', '601005000127', 1499, 1498.6446, 0.3554),
    ('SO17110026', 'MO17110826', 'MO1', '601007000001', 69, 68.102, 0.898),
    ('SO17110029', 'MO17110825', 'MO1', '40107008CM01', 238010, 237658.3374, 351.6626),
    ('SO17110029', 'MO17110825', 'MO1', '40107008CM33', 110000, 109149.843, 850.157)
;
```

```
Order_NO   | MO_NO      | DEP | PRD_NO       |    QTY | STD_QTY | QTY_DIF
:--------- | :--------- | :-- | :----------- | -----: | :------ | :------
SO17110026 | MO17110824 | MO2 | 3CA002-00120 |  40681 | 40380   | 301    
SO17110026 | MO17110824 | MO2 | 3CA002A00110 |  41125 | 40380   | 745    
SO17110026 | MO17110825 | MO1 | 403010060002 |  40381 | 40380   | 1      
SO17110026 | MO17110825 | MO1 | 601001000734 |     69 | 68      | 1      
SO17110026 | MO17110826 | MO1 | 601002000004 |   2862 | 2861    | 1      
SO17110026 | MO17110826 | MO1 | 601005000127 |   1499 | 1499    | 0      
SO17110026 | MO17110826 | MO1 | 601007000001 |     69 | 68      | 1      
SO17110029 | MO17110825 | MO1 | 40107008CM01 | 238010 | 237658  | 352    
SO17110029 | MO17110825 | MO1 | 40107008CM33 | 110000 | 109150  | 850
```

#### Expect Result

```
Order_NO   | MO_NO      | DEP  | PRD_NO       |    QTY | STD_QTY | QTY_DIF
:--------- | :--------- | :--- | :----------- | -----: | :------ | :------
SO17110026 | MO17110824 | MO2  | 3CA002-00120 |  40681 | 40380   | 301    
null       | null       | null | 3CA002A00110 |  41125 | 40380   | 745    
null       | MO17110825 | MO1  | 403010060002 |  40381 | 40380   | 1      
null       | null       | null | 601001000734 |     69 | 68      | 1      
null       | MO17110826 | MO1  | 601002000004 |   2862 | 2861    | 1      
null       | null       | null | 601005000127 |   1499 | 1499    | 0      
null       | null       | null | 601007000001 |     69 | 68      | 1      
SO17110029 | MO17110825 | MO1  | 40107008CM01 | 238010 | 237658  | 352    
null       | null       | null | 40107008CM33 | 110000 | 109150  | 850
```

---

#### Demo Test Link : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=af500701ecaf465e0356b4eb6b29029b)

Comment: That's normally something you do in your front end.

Comment: yes ,but in this case, I can't touch the front end. it's old and dirty project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can handle this using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Order_NO ORDER BY MO_NO, PRD_NO) = 1
         THEN Order_NO END AS Order_NO,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Order_NO, MO_NO ORDER BY PRD_NO) = 1
         THEN MO_NO END AS MO_NO,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Order_NO, MO_NO ORDER BY PRD_NO) = 1
         THEN DEP END AS DEP,
    PRD_NO,
    QTY,
    STD_QTY,
    QTY_DIF
FROM T
ORDER BY
    T.Order_NO,
    T.MO_NO,
    T.PRD_NO;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 3):

Use `LAG` :

```
SELECT
    IIF(Order_NO = LAG(Order_NO) OVER(ORDER BY Order_NO),  NULL, Order_NO) Order_NO,
    IIF(MO_NO = LAG(MO_NO) OVER(PARTITION BY Order_NO ORDER BY MO_NO), NULL, MO_NO) Order_NO,
    IIF(MO_NO = LAG(MO_NO)  OVER(PARTITION BY Order_NO, MO_NO ORDER BY DEP), NULL, DEP) DEP,
    PRD_NO,
    QTY,
    STD_QTY,
    QTY_DIF
FROM t
ORDER BY 
    t.Order_NO, 
    t.MO_NO,
    t.DEP
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f93ac9cff6275a8b8004467291caea87)** :

```
Order_NO   | Order_NO   | DEP  | PRD_NO       |    QTY | STD_QTY | QTY_DIF
:--------- | :--------- | :--- | :----------- | -----: | :------ | :------
SO17110026 | MO17110824 | MO2  | 3CA002-00120 |  40681 | 40380   | 301    
null       | null       | null | 3CA002A00110 |  41125 | 40380   | 745    
null       | MO17110825 | MO1  | 403010060002 |  40381 | 40380   | 1      
null       | null       | null | 601001000734 |     69 | 68      | 1      
null       | MO17110826 | MO1  | 601002000004 |   2862 | 2861    | 1      
null       | null       | null | 601005000127 |   1499 | 1499    | 0      
null       | null       | null | 601007000001 |     69 | 68      | 1      
SO17110029 | MO17110825 | MO1  | 40107008CM01 | 238010 | 237658  | 352    
null       | null       | null | 40107008CM33 | 110000 | 109150  | 850
```

Comment: Good answer +1 and use of trick for referring to the original columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : thanks for your postive feedback and sportmanship ! Appreciated.